# Dimension of Vector Space and Subspace Proof.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let *V* be a vector space, and *W* a subspace of *V*.

Prove that if $dim(V)=n$,
then $dim(W)\le dim(V)$.

I know this is supposed to be a proof by contradiction, but I'm not sure on how to tackle it.

Comment: Do you know Steinitz's exchange lemma?

Answer (score 1):

Pick a basis for $W$ of size $\dim(W)$. This is a linearly independent subset of $V$, so by a standard theorem can be extended to a basis for $V$ (of size $\dim(V)$ of course), and as this basis is a superset of the one for $W$, clearly $\dim(W) \le \dim(V)$.